# Connect MySQL DB with entity framework error

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I develop an ASP MVC 5 App with entity framwork and MySQL.
In local I run success. But when I move to hosting and run it throw exception.

> System.Data.Entity.Core.ProviderIncompatibleException: An error occurred while getting provider information from the database. This can be caused by Entity Framework using an incorrect connection string. Check the inner exceptions for details and ensure that the connection string is correct. ---> System.Data.Entity.Core.ProviderIncompatibleException: The provider did not return a ProviderManifestToken string. ---> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts. at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open() at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Open() at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Create(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings) at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.CreateNewPooledConnection() at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetPooledConnection() at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.TryToGetDriver() at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetConnection() at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open() at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices.GetDbProviderManifestToken(DbConnection connection) at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.GetProviderManifestToken(DbConnection connection) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.GetProviderManifestToken(DbConnection connection) at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbProviderServicesExtensions.GetProviderManifestTokenChecked(DbProviderServices providerServices, DbConnection connection) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbProviderServicesExtensions.GetProviderManifestTokenChecked(DbProviderServices providerServices, DbConnection connection) at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DefaultManifestTokenResolver.<>c__DisplayClass1.b__0(Tuple`3 k) at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory) at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DefaultManifestTokenResolver.ResolveManifestToken(DbConnection connection) at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbConnectionExtensions.GetProviderInfo(DbConnection connection, DbProviderManifest& providerManifest) at System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbConnection providerConnection) at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.CreateModel(LazyInternalContext internalContext) at System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryLazy`2.GetValue(TInput input) at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext() at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType) at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize() at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext() at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider() at System.Linq.Queryable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate) at Mdt.Business.CommonRepository.LoginAdmin(String username, String passwod) at Mdt.BackendWeb.Controllers.LoginController.Index(LoginAdminModel model, String returnUrl)

But I upload to another hosting, it run correctly.

I don't know why.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After talking with my hosting provider. They said they were blocked request from external internet (from outsite Vietnam, my hosting provider in Vietnam) but my DB hosting in US server, because their server has been attacking. :((